# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'

Tags: python, tkinter

```
from tkinter import *


class Canvas:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title("Canvas Demo")

        # Place a canvas in the window
        self.canvas = Canvas(window, width=200, height=100, bg="white)
        self.canvas.pack()

        # place button in frame
        frame = Frame(window)
        frame.pack()
        btRectangle = Button(frame, text="Rectangle", command=self.displayRect)
        btOval = Button(frame, text="Oval", command=self.displayOval)
        btArc = Button(frame, text="Arc", command=self.displayArc)
        btPolygon = Button(frame, text="Polygon", command=self.displayPolygon)
        btLine = Button(frame, text="Line", command=self.displayLine)
        btString = Button(frame, text="String", command=self.displayString)
        btClear = Button(frame, text="Clear", command=self.displayClear)

        btRectangle.grid(row=1, column=1)
        btOval.grid(row=1, column=2)
        btArc.grid(row=1, column=3)
        btPolygon.grid(row=1, column=4)
        btLine.grid(row=1, column=5)
        btString.grid(row=1, column=6)
        btClear.grid(row=1, column=7)

        window.mainloop()

    def displayRect(self):
        self.canvas.create_rectangle(10, 10, 190, 90, tags="rect")

    def displayOval(self):
        self.canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 190, 90, fill="red", tags="oval")

    def displayArc(self):
        self.canvas.create_arc(10, 10, 190, 90, start=0, extent=90, width=8, fill="red", tags="arc")

    def displayPolygon(self):
        self.canvas.create_polygon(10, 10, 190, 90, 30, 50, tags="rect")

    def displayLine(self):
        self.canvas.create_line(10, 10, 190, 90, fill="red", tags="line")
        self.canvas.create_line(10, 10, 190, 10, width=9, arrow="last", fill="blue", tags="line")

    def displayString(self):
        self.canvas.create_text(60, 40, text="HI, I am String", font="Times 10 bold under line", tags="string")

    def displayClear(self):
        self.canvas.delete("rect", "oval", "arc", "polygon", "line", "string")
Canvas()
```

when I run the program, the below error message displays. What is the reason for it?

```
self.canvas = Canvas(window, width=200, height=100)

TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'width'
```

Comment: You defined your own `Canvas` class, and it doesn't handle a `width` keyword argument.

Comment: `bg="white` needs a close quote. How did that quote disappear in copy and paste if it's there in your original code?

Comment: @MYGz I made the correction but now the error is TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'bg'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you are shadowing `tkinter`'s `Canvas` with the `Canvas` class you are creating.

You can use different import approach like `import tkinter as tk` and use `tk.Canvas` to avoid ambiguity or rename your class. If I were you, I'd do both.